# Can't Read static::$table_name after looping

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I get the following error messages:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 in /home/u522148874/public_html/includes/database-objects.php on line 27
>
> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 in /home/u522148874/public_html/includes/database-objects.php on line 27

Sample 1

Sample 2

When using the following code:

```
public function __construct(){
            global $MySQLDatabase;
            global $news;
           
            $this->dbh = $MySQLDatabase->open_connection();
           
            // Convert Table Fields in to Attributes
            static::$db_fields = $this->get_dbFields(static::$table_name);
            foreach(static::$db_fields as $field){
                    $this->$field = "";
            }
    }
   
    // Get Table Fields from the Database
    public function get_dbFields($table_name){
            $sql = 'DESCRIBE ' . $table_name ;
            $query = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute();
            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            // Get the quantity of the Table Columns
            $count = count($result);
            $field = array();
           
            // Loop through each column to get the 'Field'
            // ($count - 1) -> $count is minus 1 because array count starts with zero
                    // Example : Table Have 8 Columns
                    //                       $count will read it as 1 - 8 while array ($result[i]) reads it as 0 - 7
            for($i = 0; $i <= ($count - 1); $i++){
                    $field[] = $result[$i]->Field;
            }
            return $field;
    }
```

Can anyone explain to me why I am having those errors above but still can get the output (Sample 1 and Sample 2) above?

Here is my Complete Code: http://pastebin.com/xypkzs30

Comment: Please post the relevant code here

Comment: I see. My complete code is in the pastebin already.

Comment: Can you add an `echo $sql, PHP_EOL;` before the "prepare"-call in the `get_dbFields`-method? What does it show?

Comment: @vstm
DESCRIBE news DESCRIBE
Then the error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the method `DatabaseObjects::instantiate`. The first line says

```
$object = new self;
```

Now, `self` is a reference to the *current* class, that means the class in which the `instantiate`-method is implemented (`DatabaseObjects`) and not the class on which it is called.

So you don't create new `News` objects where the `table_name` is defined but `DatabaseObjects` objects which have no `table_name` defined.

You can resolve this by creating new instances using the "late static binding"-version:

```
$object = new static;
```

That way the method creates new `News` objects. You might want to also mark the `DatabaseObjects` class as `abstract`, so no accidental instantiation occurs.

Plus you might want to globally cache the `get_dbFields` method - otherwise you hit the DB for every instantiation of the `News` class (your users might fall asleep using your app).

Comment: $object = new static();

This one is the solution.
I'll still try your suggestions. ^_^

Anyways how to globally cache the get_dbFields?

Thank you so much!